# Any ways to retrive tweets based on hashtag for a time frame more than a year?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

Im looking for ways to retrieve tweets from Twitter which contains certain hashtags.
I tried to use the official API and tweepy package in Python but even with academic access I was only able to retrieve tweets which are 7 days old. I want to retrieve tweets from 2019 till 2020 but Im not able to do so with tweepy.

I tried the following packages GetOldTweet3, twint but none of them seem to work due to some changes Twitter made last year.

Can someone suggest a way to get old tweets with certain hashtags. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion provided.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have academic access, you are able to use the full archive search API available in the Twitter API v2. Tweepy has support for this via the `tweepy.Client` class. There's a [full tutorial on DEV](https://dev.to/twitterdev/a-comprehensive-guide-for-using-the-twitter-api-v2-using-tweepy-in-python-15d9), but the code will be something like this:

```py
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='REPLACE_ME')

# Replace with your own search query
query = 'from:andypiper -is:retweet'

tweets = client.search_all_tweets(query=query, tweet_fields=['context_annotations', 'created_at'], max_results=100)

for tweet in tweets.data:
    print(tweet.text)
    if len(tweet.context_annotations) > 0:
        print(tweet.context_annotations)
```

You can use search query parameters to specify the date range.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this will only retrive 100 tweets what if I need to add more?
In case of tweepy.Cursor().iterm(TWEETCOUNT = 100000) is there a way in search_all_tweets?